# webgl bufferData memory leak with chrome

Tags: webgl

I call the following line in my rendering loop, which seems to be the right way to handle drawing a constantly changing array :

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(myArray), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

This is working fine under Firefox, my array is being updated properly and there is no memory leak. However with chrome it crash the application in a few seconds, each call to bufferData increase the memory usage and nothing is freed.

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: This bug is being tracked here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365055

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

Worked around by doing it without a typed array:

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, myArray, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

This "solved" my problem.